# Copying a div on click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to copy and paste a div when clicking a button using Angular.js. Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/VjqJYW . I want the "add order line" button to add another .orderline div. I'm new to Angular and I obviously did some mistakes, because it doesn't work. What is wrong with the code?

```
$scope.orderlines=[]  
$scope.orderline = '';
$scope.addline = function(){
    $scope.items.push($scope.orderline); 
};
```

Comment: At a first glance there are a few mistakes:  $scope.items.push($scope.orderline);  => $scope.orderlines.push($scope.orderline);  next you're not doing a ngRepeat of the orderlines array. So you will always have 1 line change that as well

Comment: I have a "<div class=ng-repeat='orderline in orderlines'>". Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code pen. That I did :

Change $scope.orderline to string from object. It now represent an order line. It used when user put values from form :

```
$scope.orderline = {};
```

Change binding on qty and total (now bind on $scope.orderline):

```
<input ng-model="orderline.quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
<div flex >{{orderline.quantity * selectedItem.price}}</div>
```

Change ng-repeat (now loop on orderlines and items are named lines) :

```
<div ng-repeat='line in orderlines'>
         {{line}}
     </div>
```

Finally, update addLine to copy order line in orderLines :

```
$scope.addline = function(){
    $scope.orderline.name = $scope.selectedItem;
    $scope.orderlines.push(angular.copy($scope.orderline)); 
};
```

Here the updated plunker http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAJqZy

Comment: When you click on 'add order line' new div is created with order line data. It's not the expected ?

Comment: exactly like that. but now the 'add item' doesn''t work ;__;

Comment: Just binding errors, it's updated. But now you have a collection of order lines, so add item can't be apply unitary. So I move it in each line. If you want a global button you must loop on each lines and add it

Comment: It works great in the codepen, but in the codepen console it throws "undefined". It doesn't impact the code though. But when I change the code in my local file I get "Error: $scope.items is undefined" in the browser and the "add order line" button doesn't work.

Comment: Try to update function OrderLine and add 
          product: '' to return object

Comment: Like that: 'function OrderLine() {
        return {
          product: '',
          name: '',
          price: 0,
          qty: 0,
          totAmt: 0,
          searchText: ''
        };
      }' ?

Comment: Yes, in code pen it removed the console log. This log is throw by the directive md-autocomplete an I don't know it. If the problem persist maybe search in document of this library

Comment: It worked, hell yeah! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder if i get your idea, make them in one list and switch with your data

```
[http://codepen.io/postor/pen/OXqVvp][1]
```

Comment: No, you're just adding a line, i wanted to copy the .orderline div